# Error when using Grunt-browserify to build the npm webshot module

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, browserify

I have installed webshot from here:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/webshot

using: npm install webshot

Then I have add 'var webshot = require('webshot');' to the js file and then run:

grunt build

and typically it will compile all the npm modules into a lib.js file which I can include in my project to use npm modules on the front end.

But I get the error:

```
>> Error: module "os" not found from "/Users/Feroze/Documents/meteor_apps/Bookmark_Website/.npm/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js"
File written to: ../lib/bundle.js
>> Error: module "constants" not found from "/Users/Feroze/Documents/meteor_apps/Bookmark_Website/.npm/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js"
File written to: ../lib/bundle.js
```

When running grunt build. How come I am not able to build my lib.js file with the npm webshot module? As soon as I use npm uninstall webshot, it builds the lib.js file just fine.

Gruntfile.coffee

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      build: {
          files: ['./entrypoint.js', './package.json'],
          tasks: ['browserify2'],
          options: {
          }
      }
    },
    browserify2: {
      compile: {
        entry: './entrypoint.js',
        compile: '../lib/bundle.js'
      }
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify2');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('build', ['browserify2']);
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.3.3",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "browserify": "^4.1.9",
    "grunt-browserify": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-webshot": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "curtsy": "0.0.1"
  }
}
```

entrypoint.js

```
async = require('async')
webshot = require('webshot')
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error, perhaps this was fixed in a more recent version of browserify?  If you could add your `package.json` and `Gruntfile.js` that would be helpful.

Comment: I think the error is because you cannot use the webshot package on the front end, right? So using browserify it cannot compile webshot because of missing node modules. Did you get browserify to compile webshot?

Comment: Yeah I had no problems running `browserify` or `grunt-browserify` on my file that only required `webshot`.  Can you try to isolate it to `browserify`?  For example, I created a file `index.js` that only included `var webshot = require('webshot');` and then ran that through `browserify index.js > bundle.js` and it worked fine.

Comment: I will copy my gruntfile and package.json above that is really strange it is not working for me. I created a npm folder just to compile a lib.js file to use in my meteor project. So I created an empty folder called npm. Then I create a node_modules folder, Gruntfile.js and package.json. Then I ran command npm install which install the packages. The grunt build to build the lib.js file. With just async it works but when I try to include webshot it breaks with that error

Comment: * I meant to say bundle.js file. I use grunt build to compile a bundle.js file to include in my meteor project.

Comment: The code you pasted above fails for both `grunt-browserify2` and `browserify2`, is that the correct `Gruntfile`?

Comment: its the gruntfile I am currently using. It worked to compile the async module. But breaks when I try with webshot. I only use the command grunt build. Is there another command I should try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56445/discussion-between-dylants-and-nearpoint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to stem from using `grunt-browserify2` rather than `grunt-browserify`, the "2" version appears to be outdated and perhaps doesn't include the latest updates to `browserify`.  Try using these `package.json` and `Gruntfile.js`:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Template",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.3.3",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "browserify": "^4.1.9",
    "grunt-browserify": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "async": "^0.9.0",
    "webshot": "^0.15.0",
    "graceful-fs": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "curtsy": "0.0.1"
  }
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      build: {
          files: ['./entrypoint.js', './package.json'],
          tasks: ['browserify'],
          options: {
          }
      }
    },
    browserify: {
      vendor: {
        src: './entrypoint.js',
        dest: '../lib/bundle.js'
      }
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('build', ['browserify']);
};
```